# JenkinsのビルドでCocoapodsライブラリ(Realm)で失敗する

Tags: ios, realm, cocoapods, jenkins

### 発生している問題

Jenkins Xcode Integration プラグインを使用してビルドをすると、下記のように失敗してしまいます。

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:   Ld
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Projectname-dgejtihimgrztocykdapnwjrowrr/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Realm
>   normal arm64

Realmは0.96.0、0.96.1、0.96.2　で試してみましたが同様のエラーとなりました。

どのようなことが原因として考えられますでしょうか？

---

### 追記

ログを改めて見直しましたら下記のエラーがでていました。

```
ld: '/Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/projectname/Pods/Realm/core/librealm-ios.a(bptree-iPhoneOS-no-bitcode.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

### 環境

- Mac OS 10.10.4
- Xcode 7.0.1
- Swift 2.0
- Cocoapods で RealmSwift をインストール

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このエラーメッセージの前の部分をもう少し載せてもらえますか？このコマンンドが失敗した直接の原因が書かれているはずです。あと、失敗するのはJenkinsのビルドだけですか？Xcodeから、あるいは同じコマンドをローカルで実行した場合は成功しますか？Jenkinsが実行している実際のコマンドも書いてください。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi 
ご返答ありがとうございます。

エラーログを追記いたしました。

XcodeよりPodsプロジェクトのターゲット Realm、RealmSwiftで
[Buid Settings] - [Buid Option] - [Enable Bitcode]  を　NO
に設定することでビルドができるようになりました。
調査したところ、App Thinningという仕組みの影響と思われます。（確信がありません）

この解決方法に間違いがありましたらご指摘ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 原因はそれで合っています。bitcodeはできれば有効にしたほうがいいので、無効にするよりは有効にする方に合わせるのがいいと思います。`〜-no-bitcode.o`というバイナリはbitcodeをサポートしていない環境（Xcode 6.4）のためにあるものなので、Podsをセットアップした環境と、Jenkinsの環境およびプロジェクト設定が異なっているのではないでしょうか？Podsのセットアップをやり直す（Podsディレクトリを消して再セットアップ）とbitcodeが有効なRealmがインストールされるのではないかと思います。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi  ありがとうございます。構築した環境を見直したいと思います。